# Phoenix is ignoring csrf_token for an ajax request

Tags: ajax, elixir, csrf, phoenix-framework

I have this ajax request:

```
//..............
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-csrf-token", document.querySelector("meta[name=csrf]").content);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

On a page there's a csrf token generated by Phoenix.

```
<meta name="csrf" content="<%= Plug.CSRFProtection.get_csrf_token() %>" />
```

It's sent on a server along with each ajax request I can see in Chrome. But my server always returns:

```
"403: invalid CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) token, make sure all requests include a valid '_csrf_token' param or 'x-csrf-token' header"
```

Why? How to fix this?

Comment: Would you mind to `console.log(document.querySelector("meta[name=csrf]").content)` in your frontend code and post a result here?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the name should be "csrf-token" instead of just "csrf". This is what I use in app.html.eex (it's from the [ex_turbolinks](https://github.com/imranismail/ex_turbolinks) library readme.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<%= get_csrf_token() %>">
<meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf_token">
```

In order to use just get_csrf_token/0 in the view, however, you have to add `get_csrf_token: 0` to the list of imports from Phoenix.Controller in the `view` function in my_app_web.ex. For example:

```
lib/my_app_web.ex

def view do
  quote do
  ...
  # Import convenience functions from controllers
  import Phoenix.Controller, only: [get_flash: 2, view_module: 1, 
  get_csrf_token: 0]
  ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`name="csrf-token" id="csrf-token" value="<%= Plug.CSRFProtection.get_csrf_token() %>"` 
Try this . This is working for me

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var csrf_token = document.getElementById('csrf-token').value;
 xhr.open('POST', '/api/vote');
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", csrf_token);
```

This is my ajax request